# Using Model value includes quotation ASP MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model that I am using in my view and it has a property called list of numbers

```
public myModel{
 public string listOfNumber {get; set;}
```

then in my controller I populate it with string value

```
public myController{
 public ActionREsult myMethod(){
  ....
  myModelObj.listOfNumber  = myModelObj.listOfNumber +"["+aNumber+"]";
  return PartialView("test/_myPartialView", myModelObj);
```

in my view I have this

```
<input type="hidden" value=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.listOfNumber)) id="listNumb"/>
```

I then do a `console.log()` on the value of `$("#listNumb").val()` and get this as a result

```
"[1][4][3][23]"
```

I was wondering where is the quotation is coming from? Because when I pass back the value to the controller, using model binding and debug what it looks like I get this `\"[1][4][3][23]\"` it seem that the quotation mark became a part of the string?

**EDIT**

As suggested in one of the answer here is what it shows on view source. FYI it does not matter if I put quotation around `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.listOfNumber))` teh source shows the same thing. `""[1][4][3][23]""` notice the double quote becuase I did not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encoding the property into a JSON object, and a JSON object as a string includes quotes around it.

Imagine a different setting. If you were in javascript and did this:

```
var someObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(someValue));
```

... you'd expect that to turn into a valid object that javascript can treat as an object, right? And if that value were a string, the only way for this to work is if the string had quotes around it.

What *does* surprise me here is that your view code doesn't appear to include quotation marks, so I would have expected the string quotation marks to get interpreted as wrapping the attribute value. But perhaps the Razor engine is somehow adding those for you or something? Or perhaps the code you posted isn't the exact code you're using? What does the HTML look like when you View Source?

Comment: I left out the quotation on purpose, because my thinking was exactly like yours, where I was hoping that the string quotation marks would get interpreted as wrapping the attribute value. But it did not. Also I made the edit regarding viewing the source code

Comment: @JackThor: Interesting. So if you just do `value=@Html.Raw("test")`, will Razor generate quotation marks for you? Also, can you tell if the inner set of quotes are HTML-escaped? If they are, then that means Razor's escaping a "raw" string. If they're not, that means your browser is interpreting the double-quotes in a way that I would not expect. Something fishy here.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I tested what you asked and I get `"test"` only one set of quote. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @JackThor: That answers my question. Apparently when razor sees an HTML attribute set to an evaluated value without quotes around it (`value=@something`), it automatically puts quotes around the value. I hadn't realized it did that.